# Problems using local variables in a remote commands

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I need to write a script that takes in variables and makes a share on a remote system.

This works:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server -ScriptBlock {$a = [WMICLASS]"Win32_Share"; $a.Create("C:\test","test",0)}
```

But this doesn't:

```
$sharepath = "C:\test"
$sharename = "test"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server -ScriptBlock {$a = [WMICLASS]"Win32_Share"; $a.Create($sharepath,$sharename,0)}
```

I need a way to pass those values somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The remote session can't read your local variables, so you need to send them with your command. There's a few options here. In PowerShell 2.0 you could:

1.Pass them along with `-ArgumentList` and use [`$args[$i]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args)

```bash
$sharepath = "C:\test"
$sharename = "test"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server -ScriptBlock {
  $a = [WMICLASS]"Win32_Share"; $a.Create($args[0], $args[1], 0)
} -ArgumentList $sharepath, $sharename
```

2.Pass them along with `-ArgumentList` and use `param()` in your scriptblock to define the arguments

```bash
$sharepath = "C:\test"
$sharename = "test"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server -ScriptBlock { 
  param($sharepath, $sharename)
  $a = [WMICLASS]"Win32_Share"; $a.Create($sharepath, $sharename, 0)
} -ArgumentList $sharepath, $sharename
```

In PowerShell 3.0, the `$using:`-variable scope was introduced to make it easier:

```bash
$sharepath = "C:\test"
$sharename = "test"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server -ScriptBlock { 
  $a = [WMICLASS]"Win32_Share"; $a.Create($using:sharepath, $using:sharename, 0)
}
```

You could read more about this on [about_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables)