# PowerShell: remote execution of console application fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

While running the following snippet in powershell, I see an error(an error occurred while creating the pipeline). can anyone help me here?

```
# This file contains the list of servers you want to copy files/folders to
$computers = gc "C:\folder1\sub1\server.txt"
 
# This is the file/folder(s) you want to copy to the servers in the $computer variable
$source = "\\usa-chicago1\c$\Program Files\"
 
# The destination location you want the file/folder(s) to be copied to
$destination = "c$\July\"
$username = 'harry'
$password = 'hqwtrey$1'
$secpw = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred  = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpw)


foreach ($computer in $computers) {
if ((Test-Path -Path \\$computer\$destination)) {

     Write-Output "INSIDE IF BLOCK"
    #Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$destination -Recurse
    Invoke-Command -Computername $computer -ScriptBlock { & '\\$computer\July\' --service install --config-directory '\\$computer\July\conf' } 
    Invoke-Command -Computername $computer -ScriptBlock { & net start telegraf } 
} 
else {
    
    Write-Output $computer
    New-Item -Path "\\$computer\july\" -ItemType Directory
    Write-Output \\$computer\$destination
    Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$destination -Recurse
}
}
```

Comment: Your remotely executing script block doesn't know about local variables. You should replace `$computer` with `$using:computer` inside the script block.

Comment: Also, you should not use single quotes around an expression where you want a PowerShell variable to be evaluated. You will need to use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Script blocks passed to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...` execute *remotely*, and the remote session knows nothing about the caller's variables; refer to the caller's variables via the `$using:` scope - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28837383/45375).
- Variable references can only be embedded in *double*-quoted strings (`"..."`), whereas *single*-quoted strings (`'...'`) treat their content *verbatim* - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell string literals.

Therefore:

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $computer -ScriptBlock { 
  & "\\$using:computer\July\Telegraf\telegraf" --service install --config-directory "\\$using:computer\July\Telegraf\conf"
}
```

---

As for the **nondescript error message** you saw, `RuntimeException: An error occurred while creating the pipeline.`:

This should be considered a ***bug***; you should see `&: The term '\\$computer\July\Telegraf\telegraf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`, as you would get with *local* invocation.

The bug, which only surfaces with *UNC* paths, is being tracked in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13226).