# Pass local variable to invoke-command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am executing the below Powershell script from a remote server. However it is failing as follows:

```
PS C:\\Windows\\system32\> Invoke-Command -Session $evServerSession -scriptblock {

\\>\> $ListArchiveNames = Get-Content "E:\\Utilities\\MyScripts\\EXOmigration\\ArchivePermissions\\ArchivesList.txt"

\\>\> Foreach ($ArchiveName in $ListArchiveNames) {
  Get-EVArchive -ArchiveName $ArchiveName |
    Get-EVArchivePermission |
      Export-Csv -Path E:\\Utilities\\MyScripts\\EXOmigration\\ArchivePermissions\\$NewTrusteesList.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force}

\\>\>

\\>\> }
```

```
cls
#==============
$NewTrusteesList = Read-Host "Please enter the migration Transvault group name here " 
$NewTrusteesList = $NewTrusteesList + "-ArchiveTrustees" + $dateStr 
New-Item  E:\Utilities\MyScripts\EXOmigration\ArchivePermissions\$NewTrusteesList.csv -ItemType File

#------------
#--------------------Establish an EV PS session-----------------------------
$evServerSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName cov-msv-prd009.morganlewis.net -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Powershell32
Invoke-Command -Session $evServerSession -scriptblock {
Add-PSSnapin Symantec.EnterpriseVault.PowerShell.Snapin
}

#--------------------Run pertinent PS scripts-------------------------------
Invoke-Command -Session $evServerSession -scriptblock {
  $ListArchiveNames = Get-Content 
  "E:\Utilities\MyScripts\EXOmigration\ArchivePermissions\ArchivesList.txt"
  Foreach ($ArchiveName in $ListArchiveNames) {
    Get-EVArchive -ArchiveName $ArchiveName |
      Get-EVArchivePermission | Export-Csv -Path 
    E:\Utilities\MyScripts\EXOmigration\ArchivePermissions\$NewTrusteesList.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
  }
}

#------------------------Clean up the session----------------------------
$evServerSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$Using:variable_name` to include `variable_name` [local variable in a command run on a remote computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.4#example-9-include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer)

Example:

```
$Log = 'PowerShellCore/Operational'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WinEvent -LogName $Using:Log -MaxEvents 10
}
```

Comment: If you believe this to be the solution to the OP's problem (it's unclear at this point), you should have voted to close the question as a duplicate instead of providing an answer, given that this solution has been provided many times before, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28837672/45375).